# Serialize/De-serialize Scala future

Tags: java, scala

Is it possible serialize a Scala Future into `byte[]` and then deserialize it again?.

And if is possible, does someone know the best approach?

Comment: As it stands, question is too broad. You should either narrow the scope to Java's default serialization, or to a specific serialization library (ex. Kryo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be possible with the standard-implementation of Futures in scala.
Future clearly doesn't implement the interface Serializable and isn't supposed to be serialized.

The question is, what would happen when the Future isn't finished yet.
The Future gets executed because it's task is scheduled in the ExecutionContext.
If one would serialize this Future and deserialize it on another JVM, then the task would only be scheduled on the first JVM. On the second JVM, the future would never get its result.

It probably makes more sense to serialize the content of a Future, as soon as it is ready.

Comment: completely agree, but in my case the execution was in the same JVM, still I dont know how come the Monix Task[+A] extends Serializable it is, and can work async

Comment: Monix execution is (sometimes?) done lazy. I think they retrigger the execution of the task, as soon as it is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
println(if ((concurrent.Future{}).isInstanceOf[Serializable]) "Yes" else "No")
```

prints

```
No
```